# Which way of returning list is better? New in local or Clear in local

Tags: return, call

For example:

1. New in local

   ```
   class AAA{
    public List<STH> GetList(){
    List<STH>list = new List<STH>();
    //do something
    return list;}
   }
   ```
2. Clear in local

   ```
   class BBB{
     List<STH> list = new List<STH>();
     public List<STH> GetList(){
       list.Clear();
       //do something
       return list;
     }
   }
   ```

Who calls `GetList()` takes the lists which returned as his field.
Which way is the better way?